# tkmessagebox askquestion with multiple answers

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkmessagebox

I've been trying to get tkmessagebox.askquestion to ask a question where there are more answers than 'yes' and 'no.' I know that askquestion returns a string 'yes' when yes is clicked, and I'm trying to add more buttons to that dialogue box. Can this even be done with tkmessagebox? How could I add more button options (i.e., 'pass' and 'abstain' in addition to 'yes' and 'no')?

Comment: Have you managed this? If so, can you please post the relevant code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible with tkMessageBox.

The type option of the [Dialog class](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/09811ecd5df1/Lib/lib-tk/tkCommonDialog.py) (used by tkMessageBox) only allows the values `abortretryignore`, `ok`, `okcancel`, `retrycancel`, `yesno`, and `yesnocancel`. You can use these with your Dialog subclasses, but if you want to show more buttons I recommend you to use a Toplevel widget and add them to the window or define your own class.

Comment: A code example for doing that would be appreciated.